# Apply multiple filter categories to a list of <li>(s) with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this fiddle  and I want to know how I can implement filtering function based on two categories. when someone click the filter, it should get the values from both the current filters selection, hide the list and show only the filter result. Any idea on how to implement this step? any help would be appreciated!!

```
<ul style='list-style-type: none;' class="filter1">
<li><span class="filtercat1">red</span>

</li>
<li><span class="filtercat1">blue</span>

</li>
<li><span class="filtercat1">yellow</span>

</li>
<li><span class="filtercat1">all</span>

</li>
</ul> <span id="filterbutton1">
    <a href="#" id="prev">« Previous</a> 
    <a href="#" id="next">Next »</a>

</span>

<ul style='list-style-type: none;' class="filter2">
<li><span class="filtercat2">orange</span>

</li>
<li><span class="filtercat2">apple</span>

</li>
<li><span class="filtercat2">papaya</span>

</li>
<li><span class="filtercat2">all</span>

</li>
</ul> <span id="filterbutton2">
    <a href="#" id="prev2">« Previous</a>
    <a href="#" id="next2">Next »</a>
</span>

<ul id='list'>
<li class="">red orange</li>
<li class="">red apple</li>
<li class="">red papaya</li>
<li class="">blue orange</li>
<li class="">blue apple</li>
<li class="">blue papaya</li>
<li class="">yellow orange</li>
<li class="">yellow apple</li>
<li class="">yellow papaya</li>
</ul>
<span id="filterbutton">
    <a href="#" id="filter"> filter</a>

<span id="resetbutton">
    <a href="#" id="reset"> reset</a>
```

```
$(function () {
    var all = $('.filtercat1').addClass("passiv");

    var i = -1;

    $('#prev' ).click(function () {
        ctrlbutton(i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i);
    });
    $('#next').click(function () {
        ctrlbutton(i = ++i % all.length);
    }).click();

    function ctrlbutton(ele) {
        all.removeClass("active").addClass("passiv");
        all.eq(ele).removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");
    }


})

$(function () {
    var all = $('.filtercat2').addClass("passiv");

    var i = -1;

    $('#prev2').click(function () {
        ctrlbutton(i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i);
    });
    $('#next2').click(function () {
        ctrlbutton(i = ++i % all.length);
    }).click();

    function ctrlbutton(ele) {
        all.removeClass("active").addClass("passiv");
        all.eq(ele).removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");
    }


})
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BlacBunny/5tfcuy1w/

Comment: If red is selected in 1st list and apple in second list then it should show every result of red as well as apple. Right?

Comment: Unclear to me explain one more time from the start

Comment: @learning it should only show "red apple", but it seemed like you already answered the question, plus the extra reset function! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
$("#list").find("li").each(function(){
    this.className = "all "+this.innerHTML;
});
    $("#filter").click(function(){
        var class1 = $(".filter1").find(".active").text();
        var class2 = $(".filter2").find(".active").text();
        $("#list").find("li").addClass("passiv").end().find("."+class1+"."+class2)
        .removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");
    });
    $("#reset").click(function(){
        $("#list").find("li").addClass("active").removeClass("passiv");
    });
```

I have not optimized this code. You are using dom ready function two times which is actually not required.

You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsss/5tfcuy1w/5/)

Answer (score 0):

#### [**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/happysmiles/5tfcuy1w/3/)

This function will be called every time the filters are modified. The values of `filter1` and `filter2` must be modified per click to the filter buttons.

```
var filter1 = 'red'; // initial value of filter1
var filter2 = 'orange'; // initial value of filter2

function filterList() {
    var list = $('#list li');
    
    list.each(function(index, item) {
        var itemContents = $(item).text();
        
        if (itemContents.indexOf(filter1) >= 0 && itemContents.indexOf(filter2) >= 0) {
            $(item).show();
        } else {
            console.log('hide ' + itemContents);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it was based on the user's code actually. We can optimize it to use only one DOM ready function

Comment: thanks! but the filter should only be applied when filter button is clicked, not directly changed

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baga143/jtoaLqug/)

```
$("#filter").click(function() {
    var filterCat1 = $(".filter1 .active").text();
    var filterCat2 = $(".filter2 .active").text();


    $("#list li").each( function( index, element ){
        var text = $(element).text();
        if((text.indexOf(filterCat1) < 0 && filterCat1 != "all") 
           || (text.indexOf(filterCat2) < 0 && filterCat2 != "all"))
            $(element).removeClass("active").addClass("passiv");
        else
            $(element).removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the contains selector

```
$('#filter').click(function() {
    $("#list li").addClass("passiv");
    var filter1 = $(".filter1 span.active").text();
    var filter2 = $(".filter2 span.active").text();

    var filter= (filter1 == "all" ? "" : filter1) + " " + (filter2 == "all" ? "" : filter2);

    $('#list li:contains("' + filter + '")').removeClass("passiv");        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5tfcuy1w/10/